# How to use Jquery ajax to set $_SESSION?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to create a simple log in system that uses ajax but the problem I am having it wont set the $_SESSION.

**login.js:**

```
 $('#bt-login').click(function(){
        var login = $('#login').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'widgets/Login/loginFunction.php',
            data: login,
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg){alert(msg)}
        });
});
```

**loginFunction.php:**

```
 <?php
     include_once '../../dbConfig.php';
     include_once '../../config.php';

     session_start();

      $usr = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
      $pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
      $remember = intval($_POST['rememberMe']);

      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT usr, id FROM members WHERE usr='".$usr."' AND pass='".md5($pass)."'"));

      if($row['usr']){
          $_SESSION['usr'] = $row['usr'];
          $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
          $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $remember;
          setcookie('DirtPileGames',$remember);
      }

 ?>
```

Now for some reason loginFunction.php is not setting the $_SESSION. I do a refresh and $_SESSION is blank.

Does anyone have any ideas why this wont work.

Comment: This is what I have figured out so far. I am using session_name function so it creates a cookie with my desired name. When ajax is run then it will create a different cookie called PHPSESSID. So I just have to figure out how to name it without having a second cookie made. Oh yeah, if I don't include the session_name then the script does work correctly.

Comment: Ok I think I have figured it out. I had to put the session_name and session_set_cookie_params on the main file and on the ajax file. I don't know if this is right but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the specific problem, because the session should be valid assuming you're not accidentally calling session_destroy() somewhere. Some advice for debugging - make sure the session_id() matches on the pages; if it doesn't something funny is going on. Could try explicitly calling session_write_close(). In addition set something in $_SESSION for the error case (when the user doesn't exist) to make sure its not a simple logic error. Also, don't use an md5 pretty please. Use some variant of sha, and salt it.

Edit: you mention session_name()

This call fixes the name of the session so you can refer to it on other pages. If you do a session_start() on another page without naming the session identically, it will spawn a new session with a new id.

Note from the php documentation: The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name at request startup time. Thus, you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called).

Comment: I did the session_id and I am getting two different id's. The main part of the site I am getting 33a77eefa3a27732485fd86245661548 but the php file used for my ajax I am getting 7c54561b0fcb89765db0b9da4a2a83d3.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call session_start() every time you want to access or set session variables.  It will be blank when you refresh a page unless you first call session_start().

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are dependent on cookies, try an leave out the

```
setcookie('DirtPileGames',$remember);
```

See if this clears up the issue, a lot of problems  depend on your php stack.